# Audio playback issues in 12.10: Mic feeds back through the headphones, but I can't hear any other audio

Tags: 12.10, sound

I had a system crash yesterday, and ever since then my audio playback isn't working any more in 12.10. I've gone through several of the steps outlined in restoring audio (I see that it's a common problem) and I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Pulseaudio. The odd thing is I'm getting a lot of white noise through the headphones and when I unmute my mic I can hear what I'm saying through the headphones. It all worked perfectly fine up until the system crash. I'm wondering if the crash is related to my video card. It's a 5870 and I've been trying to use the proprietary drivers. Perhaps sound has been routed to the HDMI cable? ALSAmixer says everything is unmuted and the volume levels are appropriate.

Comment: What "steps" did you already try? Did you also remove `~/.pulse`, resp. `~/.config/pulse`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing Pavucontrol from Software Centre and check all of your sound card settings with that to make sure everything is setup 100% and nothing has changed after the crash...